# Dyalog APL dyadic operator deriving ambivalent function to pair two function results

Tags: array, functional-programming, apl, composition

I'm writing a small utility operator which applies two functions to an argument pair and strands the results. The pair can either be given as two arguments or as a single argument with two elements. Either way, the left operand is applied to the left value and the right operand to the right value:

```
_n_←{⍺←⊢ ⋄ (a b)←⍺ ⍵ ⋄ (⍺⍺ a)(⍵⍵ b)}
```

Here is example usage for computing the factorial and the negation:

```
      4 !_n_- 10
16 ¯10
      !_n_- 4 10
16 ¯10
```

And here's the reverse and the unique:

```
      3 1 4 1 5⌽_n_∪2 7 1 8
┌─────────┬───────┐
│5 1 4 1 3│2 7 1 8│
└─────────┴───────┘
      ⌽_n_∪(3 1 4 1 5)(2 7 1 8)
┌─────────┬───────┐
│5 1 4 1 3│2 7 1 8│
└─────────┴───────┘
```

However, this seems like a lot of plumbing for what is essentially a trivial operator. **Can it be done more elegantly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow Behind, then  `_n_←{⍺←⊣ ⋄ ⍺ ⍺⍺⍛,∘⍵⍵/⍤,⍵}` is arguably  aesthetically nicer. However, this will just blindly concatenate left and right arguments, so if we need higher-ranked ones to stay separate, then the less pretty `_n_←{⍺←⊣ ⋄ ⍺ ⍶⍛,⍥⊂∘⍹/⍤,⍥⊂⍵}` variation is probably needed.

Comment: This is so clever! However, my example case was too simple. Now updated. You can fix your code by inserting `⍥⊂` to the right of each `,`

Comment: Btw, even without Behind, we can write `_n_←{⍺←⊣ ⋄ ⊃⍺,⍨∘⍺⍺⍨⍥⊂∘⍵⍵/⍤,⍥⊂⍵}`

Comment: @Adám Drats. The Enclose-less version is so nice, I was hoping you just needed scalar arguments. Added.